# iframe tag opens doubleClick link in iPhone's native Safari browser

Tags: ios, iframe, double-click-advertising

When my web-checkout page loads in my iOS app (swift), user are automatically re-directed to a doubleClick link in phones native safari browser. Any idea how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. Just look for the URL in debug console and blacklist the URL. That's how i resolved the issue